# Typescript: how to select class property by dynamic string

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I use class based Nuxt with Typescript and get an error when trying to target a property dynamically by a string.

The error is:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`${string}Products`' can't be used 
to index type 'default'
```

I didn't find a solution that worked for me yet..

Here is the code:

```
export default class extends Vue {

  stateProducts: any[] = [];

  get paperProducts() {
    return this.stateProducts.filter((x) => x.productType === 0);
  }
  get digitalProducts() {
    return this.stateProducts.filter((x) => x.productType === 1);
  }

 getProductStyle(productType: string) { 
    const type:string = productType === 'paper' ? 'digital' : 'paper';
 
    if (!(this[`${type}Products`]).length) {       // <----------------------- error
       
      return 'col-xs-6 col-ms-4 col-sm-3';
    }
    return'col-xs-6 ';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `:string` type annotation to `type` constant. When using `:string` you're unnecessarily broadening the type that originally would be `'digital' | 'paper'`, hence making TS complain.